# Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition: Can I insert default code in every .cpp file I create?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, editor

If I have for example this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

When I create an empty project with Visual C++ 2008, how to insert this code in every .cpp file I create in this project?

Comment: Why not put them into a precompiled header? This sort of thing is actually "correct use" of precompiled headers, i.e. for system ones that never change and that you include often.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an item template which would be a .cpp file with all the necessary includes. Then when you add a file to the project you would add that item instead of an empty .cpp file.

Item templates are located here:

```
%USER%\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Templates\ItemTemplates
```

[Guide on creating project and item templates.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s365byhx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Not there.  It is vc/vcprojectitems/newc++file.cpp

Comment: @HansPassant Could you edit my answer with this please? I have no visual studio on this machine so I cannot check the paths.

Answer (score 1):

Properties on the project then `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced`, there you will find a field for `Force Includes`. Just write the name of a header there which in turn contains the includes.